# Svelte form on:submit type TypeScript

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am trying to build a simple form in Svelte TypeScript.

My on:submit looks like this: `<form on:submit={onSubmit}>`, and my onSubmit function is defined as:

```
const onSubmit = (event: HTMLFormElement) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch("addPerson", person);
    person = {
      name: "",
      isOwed: 0,
    };
  };
```

With this code I get the TypeScript problem:

> Type '(event: HTMLFormElement) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventHandler<Event, HTMLFormElement>'.
> Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.

I get that the event passed to onSubmit has the type `EventHandler<Event, HTMLFormElement>`, and that my function is only expecting HTMLFormElement, but I can't manage to expect the whole EventHandler object. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The event type is a `SubmitEvent`.

```
function handleSubmit(e: SubmitEvent) {
 const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement)
}
```

```html
<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead.

```
<script lang="ts">    
      const handleSubmit: svelte.JSX.EventHandler<Event, HTMLFormElement> = () => {

      }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `event` parameter is an `Event`, not a `HTMLFormElement` HTML node. So you can replace `event: HTMLFormElement` to `event: Event` or even better (as suggested by TypeScript): `event: EventHandler<Event, HTMLFormElement>`.

Comment: Where does `EventHandler` come from ?

Comment: Can't try it right now but it probably comes from the svelte's types definition file.